# Try to update, if update fails then delete (RubyOnRails-PostgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to, update a record, however if it fails due to unique validation,
then I am deleting the record since the intended record is already present.

```
def update_dependent_model(records, foreign_key, foreign_key_id)
  records.each do |record|
    begin
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        record.update_column(foreign_key.to_sym, foreign_key_id)
      end
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique, PG::UniqueViolation => e
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'ROLLBACK'
      record.delete
    end
  end
end
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this code.
Some records that are to be deleted or not getting deleted.
Logs don't help either. Shows no error.

Also, the weird thing about logs is:

```
  SQL (2.4ms)  UPDATE "records" SET "foriegn_key_id" = 220 WHERE "records"."id" = $1  [["id", 124080]]
  SQL (0.6ms)  UPDATE "records" SET "foriegn_key_id" = 220 WHERE "records"."id" = $1  [["id", 153032]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "records" SET "foriegn_key_id" = 220 WHERE "records"."id" = $1  [["id", 124099]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  UPDATE "records" SET "foriegn_key_id" = 220 WHERE "records"."id" = $1  [["id", 176549]]
  SQL (0.5ms)  UPDATE "records" SET "foriegn_key_id" = 220 WHERE "records"."id" = $1  [["id", 162725]]
  SQL (0.8ms)  UPDATE "records" SET "foriegn_key_id" = 220 WHERE "records"."id" = $1  [["id", 124109]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
  SQL (0.3ms)  DELETE FROM "records" WHERE "records"."id" = $1  [["id", 124109]]
```

Actually as per this the record with id `124080` has gotten updated, but strangely in DB this record is still present.

Comment: `124080 has gotten updated, but strangely in DB this record is still present.` Why shouldn't it be? Updating the `foriegn_key_id` does not remove the row.

Comment: You should not explicitly execute the rollback as leaving the transaction with an exception should do that for you already. It is a bit hard to see what is wrong here: from the log it seems to be working, only record with id=124109 has thrown an exception and so only that record is deleted? Are you sure your validations are defined correctly? (and where are they defined: in the database or in rails?)

Comment: Aside? `foriegn_key_id`? Typo? `foreign_key_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the whole operation in single transaction like below

```
def update_dependent_model(records, foreign_key, foreign_key_id)
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    records.each do |record|
      record.update_column(foreign_key.to_sym, foreign_key_id)
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique, PG::UniqueViolation => e
      record.delete
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could encapsulate the logic in a server-side function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_update_or_delete(_id int, _value int) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   UPDATE records
   SET    foriegn_key_id = _value
   WHERE  id = _id;

EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN   -- error code 23505
   DELETE FROM records WHERE id _id;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But it's cheaper to avoid raising an exception to begin with:

```
WITH cte AS (
   UPDATE records
   SET    foreign_key_id = _value
   WHERE  id = _id
   AND    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT FROM records
      WHERE  id = _id
      AND    foreign_key_id = _value
      )
   RETURNING 1
   )
DELETE FROM records
WHERE  id = _id
AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM cte);
```

Neither of these, nor your original are **concurrency-safe**.

There is race condition between the lookup in the `EXISTS` subquery and the actual `UPDATE` - or the following `DELETE`. The longer your transaction is uncommitted, the bigger the chance that you end up deleting rows in error - because a blocking row has been deleted by a concurrent transaction in the meantime or a concurrent transaction causing the unique violation was rolled back.

Since you cannot lock rows that are not there in Postgres, the *completely* safe way would be to use [`SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/transaction-iso.html) (and retry on serialization failure) or lock the whole table or use [advisory locks](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS) in a consistent fashion.